# Sublime Text + Anaconda not indenting Python code correctly

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

Running:

- Sublime Text 3.2.2
- Python 3.8.2

Anaconda's autoformat feature reindents the code below as follows:

```py
    counter = 0

    def print_this():

      print("Hello World.")
      return

      def main(counter):

        if counter < 10:
          print_this()
          counter += 1
          main(counter)
        else:
          print("All done.")
          return


          main(counter)
```

What adjustments do the Anaconda linting settings need to get the reindentation to format code properly?

Comment: I can't reproduce this...

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

In the top panel access to **View->Indentation->Tab Width: 4 space**

[image]